# Copy a Column without Warning message in Pandas

Tags: pandas, copy, warnings, message

I would like to copy 1 column of the Dataframe, but I get always a warning message: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." I know it is because of Chained assignment, I only can't find a proper solution:

This is the first method which is not works:

```
data3['Close2'] = data3['Close']
```

I tried another methods, just like below, but nothing of them works:

```
data3['Close2'] = data3['Close'].copy()
data3['Close2']=data3['Close'].values
data3['Close_input'] = data3['Close'].copy(deep=True)
data3['Close_input'] = data3.loc[:, ('Close')] 
data3.Close_input = data3.Close

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How should I modify my code to avoid warning messages?

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: problem here is how is created `df3`, e.g. if some filter like `df3 = df[mask]` need `df3 = df[mask].copy()`

Comment: Thanks, taht was the sulotion!!!